# Conectar MySQL con java en NetBeans usando Maven

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, maven

Buen día estoy teniendo un problema al conectarme a una base de datos MySQL usando Maven desde un pequeño proyecto web que he creado en NetBeans. Este es el código que uso para la conexión.

```
protected Connection conectar = null;
private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/prueba";
private final String usuario = "root";
private final String password = "";

public void abrirConexion(){
    try{
        conectar = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
        System.out.println("Conexión Exitosa");
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Error al abrir Conexión: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

En el pom.xml tengo la dependencia que copie de la página de MVNrepository

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Pero al hacer un debug me arroja el sgte. mensaje:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/prueba
```

Probé en una aplicación de escritorio y se conecta normal e incluso pude obtener los datos de una tabla pero en un proyecto web no. Les agradecería mucho que me puedan ayudar con este inconveniente. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la conexión con jdbc no importa la Clase Driver correspondiente a la librería que tengas en el proyecto, es un error común ya que esperarías que se cargue automáticamente según la librería que utilices pero para este tipo de conexión no es así, para precargar la clase Driver de MySql realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
public void abrirConexion(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // De esta forma cargamos la clase Driver de MySQL.
        conectar = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
        System.out.println("Conexión Exitosa");
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Error al abrir Conexión: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo, con tu respuesta pude solucionar el inconveniente. Aunque el día de ayer yo tenía agregada esa línea de código del Class.forName pero igual tenía el mismo error, buscando alguna solución por internet encontré que ya no era necesario esa línea de código por eso la retiré, también decían que ahora el driver era así "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" pero igual con eso me salía error. Ahora prendo mi laptop, hago un debug al proyecto agregando lo que me dijiste tú y oh si pudo conectarse con la bd. Que habría pasado no sé, pero te agradezco por responder, por ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Que bien que te haya funcionado, como no se cual es tu ambiente de desarrollo, según recuerdo después de JDK 6 los driver se deberían cargar automáticamente, verifica que la versión de Java que esta ejecutando tu proyecto es superior a la 6.

Comment: Una prueba que puedes realizar después de verificar la JDK  es colocar el puerto en la URL `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306` y quitar el Class.forName.

Comment: Tengo el JDK 14 colocando o no el puerto si conecta, el problema es quitando el Class.forName ahí es cuando se produce el error. Gracias por tu ayuda de todas maneras.